# CompletableFuture.runAsync at fixed rate

Tags: concurrency, java-8

The [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) is very powerful when it comes to joining futures. Among other advantages (execute something when the task finishes, execute something on an exception, etc) it has the option to run tasks in the background using [runAsync](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync-java.lang.Runnable-).

What it lacks though is the possibility to have a task run periodically, similar to [ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-).

Does anyone know how to have a task running periodically using a CompletableFuture? I tried using an endless loop in the task itself, however one loses the option to cancel a task using the future's [cancel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#cancel-boolean-) method.

Comment: That’s not what `CompletableFuture` is made for. A `CompletableFuture` represents a single completion. You are probably looking for the [`Flow` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/Flow.html).

Comment: You can hack this by specifying the executor to schedule it to run in the future. In JDK9,  `CompletableFuture#delayedExecutor` is an adapter using a global `ScheduledExecutorService` thread.